# How can I fill the space between a left and right float without making the right float wrap?

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is for all the elements to be on the same line, but have the `text-overflow` kick in if the paragraph in the middle is wider than the available space, but if not, then the right float should still be in the same line.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hHvCA

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle">
    <p>Can this paragraph fill the space between the left and right floats without making the right float wrap?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outer {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  background-color: #555;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  background-color: #777;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}

#middle {
   background-color: #999;
   height: 100px;
}

#middle > p {
   line-height: 100px;
   color: #eee;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Try to add float left to each class. (Left middle right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a

```
float: left
```

on the #middle one. Also, try setting a `width`, to avoid the middle div spanning to 100%

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments below, your best bet is to use a proper grid system. Twitter Bootstrap has two great choices [Default Grid System](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and [Fluid Grid System](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem). In addition, you can package Bootstrap from their website to only include the modules you need.

Otherwise, with the typo in `# middle` fixed, you can use `float: left` on `#middle` to make `#right` not wrap. You will also need to use JavaScript to set the width on `#middle` based on screen-size, or you risk the text being too long and pushing `#right` down again. A solution is easier to accomplish with a grid system!

I wrote the JS to work on `window.onload`, you could also do on a resize.

Modified code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfwJi

Comment: +1 for this, additional OP should look at using a grid system to help this process.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Also, this is what I had at first and is a very obvious solution but not quite what I was after. I've edited the question to describe exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Good point. A flexible grid framework like that provided by Twitter's Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) would be great.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I am on a 1080p monitor, so did not see that occurring. You could try setting a width on `#middle` using JavaScript based on the screen size. Otherwise, a static/fluid grid system is your best bet I believe.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution:

```
#middle {
   background-color: #999;
   height: 100px;
   float:left;
   width:1364px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try floating the middle div to left as well. That should work.

```
     #middle {
         background-color: #999;
         height: 100px;
         float:left;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float: left;` in `#middle > p`

```css
#middle > p {
 line-height: 100px;
 color: #eee;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: monospace;
 float: left; /* change here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9N3Fs/1/). Check it out, it pretty much solves your problem.

Moreover, I would like to suggest you using a grid system as it will help you in making the website in a lot more easier way with very or no little problems!

**CSS:**

```
#outer {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  background-color: #555;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  background-color: #777;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#middle {
   background-color: #999;
   height: 100px;
    width: 72%;
    float:left;
}

#middle > p {
   line-height: 100px;
   color: #eee;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: monospace;
}
```

Take a look at [this site](http://www.xhtmljunction.com/blog/10-popular-css-grid-systems-for-a-website/), provides 10 CSS grid systems! :)