# hr line between two divs

Tags: html, css

Following is my fiddle in which I am trying to give hr line between two `floating` divs . Kindly let me know how can I give a responsive line between two floating divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/NH5Lc/5/

```
<div style="display:inline-block; float: left;">Calories</div>
<div style="inline-block">
    <hr class="between" />
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; float: right;">20</div>
<br/>
<div style="display:inline-block; float: left;">Calories</div>
<div style="inline-block">
    <hr class="between" />
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; float: right;">20</div>
```

Comment: you could do that with a border instead of a hr tag. Of the record, it would be better to use a css file instead of inline styles

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fill the space between a left and right float without making the right float wrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259220/how-can-i-fill-the-space-between-a-left-and-right-float-without-making-the-right)

Comment: @GertB. I did the inline styling for the fiddle only. Issues are the the third div always goes to next line and margins from the hr lines are not workning

Comment: @flyx my question is different and also that question is not answered.

Comment: Isn't a table element the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` too. **[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NH5Lc/9/)**

```css
    .between {
        border: 3px dotted #0099CC;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    .parent
    { 
        display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
        display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
        display:-ms-flexbox; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
        display:box;
        width:100%;
    }
    .child2
    {
        -moz-box-flex:5.0; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-box-flex:5.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -ms-flex:9.0; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
        box-flex:9.0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='child1'>Calories</div>
        <div class='child2'> <hr class="between" /></div>
        <div class='child3'>20</div>
    </div>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='child1'>Calories as dasd as dasd</div>
        <div class='child2'> <hr class="between" /></div>
        <div class='child3'>20</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What if the text is Total Carbohydrates it will not look nice then. In your fiddle the line is not dynamically squeezing as per the text

Comment: @user3027531 Answer and fiddle updated. check it again.

Answer (score 1):

paste it your between class
.between {

```
width: 500px;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid gray;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`<div style="border-top:1px solid black; width:100%;"></div>` will do it. As Gert B. says, you should really be using a linked file rather than inline styles though. In which case, you would have in your CSS file:

```
.line{
     border-top:1px solid black;
     width:100%
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you could use a `<table>` or at least a list `<ul>` for what you are trying to do .

With a list, you can use text-align, float and pseudo-element .
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Bmhqc

```
ul, li {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:right;
}
li em {
  float:left;
}
li em:after {
  content:'';
  border-bottom:dotted;
  width:2000px;
  margin-right:-2000px;/* reduce space needed to 0 */
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
li, span {
  background:white;
  overflow:hidden; /* hide pseudo line overflow */
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li><em>calorie</em><span>20</span></li>
  <li><em>calorie</em><span>20</span></li>
  <li><em>calorie</em><span>20</span></li>
  <li><em>calorie</em><span>20</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am making it responsive so width `2000px` won't work for me

Comment: have you tried ? and understood the purpose of the negative margin ?

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
   <div id="outer">
    <div id="left">Calories</div>
    <div id="middle">
        <hr class="between" />
    </div>
    <div id="right">20</div>
</div>

<br>
    <br>
    <div id="outer">
    <div id="left">Calories</div>
    <div id="middle">
        <hr class="between" />
    </div>
    <div id="right">20</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   #outer {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    width: 100px;  
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
#right {
    width: 200px;
  
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
}
#middle {
   
    float: left;
}
.between {
    border: 3px dotted #0099CC;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

## [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzXp5/4/)